# Android App How to Force Clean Install instead of Upgrade

Tags: android

After an upgrade on my app, I'm having problems with freezing. If I do clean install (uninstall and then install), the problem doesn't happen.

Does anyone have any idea what could be causing this? Or, how to force a clean install on upgrade rather than upgrade?

Or any other ideas/solutions...

Thanks!

Comment: Please be more specific as to what's causing the freeze. Is this a DB-driven application? Preference Pane?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, the database of the app is changed and this is not correctly processed. During the update of the application the database is not deleted. During deinstallation it is deleted and then created once again.

Answer (score 0):

It would be very useful to figure out what exactly is causing it to fail once it is upgraded. For example if it is the DB you could programatically delete the database forcing it to be recreated (or upgrade it).

Answer (score 0):

You are probably loading settings on the Activity's onCreate method and you are not checking if the data structure has changed.

You could do something like this:

```
    try {
        //DataModel.LoadSettings(); //Exception
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //Settings settings = new Settings(); //You format the settings here to the match the data structure
        //DataModel.SaveSettings(); //And save the settings
    }
```